# 英語が残っている: モバイル版サイトのアプリダウンロード用リンク

Tags: バグ, 完了, 英語

モバイル版サイトをiPhoneのSafari等で見ると、サイト下部にStack Exchangeのアプリのリンクが表示されるが、英語表記になっている。
翻訳は「Stack ExchangeのiOSアプリのダウンロード」とかで良いと思う。
[image: 指摘用画像]

Comment: リンクをクリックすると、ちゃんと日本のアップルストアに転送させますか？

Comment: はい、ちゃんと転送されています。

Comment: リンクを外したため「status-completed」としてタグつけます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

実は、モバイルアプリの他言語化がまだ計画していないため、リンクを翻訳しても、アプリは英語しかありません。

その場合、どうしましょうか？

1. 英語のアプリの為、英語のリンクを残す
2. リンクを日本語に変えますが、「英語のみ」を指摘する
3. リンクを外す（モバイルサイトは他言語化になる）

Comment: 私としては3.が良いと思います。